# Positioning the logo in the first page of the presentation, near the title of the conference

Tags: beamer, positioning, beamer-metropolis

I would like to reproduce the following slide in the first page of my presentation:

[image]

(the light blue block would be the conference logo)

I'm using the following theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[sectionpage=none, progressbar=frametitle, numbering=fraction]{metropolis}        % Use metropolis theme  
\title{Title}
\date{\today}
\author{Author}
\institute{Title}

% logo of my university
\titlegraphic{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(50,0){\makebox(0,0)[rt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}}}
  \end{picture}}
\AtBeginSection[]{
\begin{frame}{Talk Overview}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
\frame{\sectionpage}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

This produces a result like this:

[image]

How can I modify my Latex code to obtain, e.g., the conference name to the right of the logo and the title of the talk immediately below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility: place the image and conference names besides each other with `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[sectionpage=none, progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\title{Title}
\date{\today}
\author{Author}
\institute{Title}


% logo of my university
\titlegraphic{%
\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
Conference Title
\end{minipage}%
  }
\AtBeginSection[]{
\begin{frame}{Talk Overview}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
\frame{\sectionpage}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```